# JSON.net - field is either string or List<string>

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, json.net

I have a situation where the `JSON` returned from a `REST`-service returns a list of Movie-objects, all specced out with a ton of information. A couple of fields in that `REST`-service result changes depending on the information available.

An example: A Movie always has some screen captures (images), actors and directors. Depending on the movie in question, there might be one or more images, one or more actors and one or more directors. Sample JSON for a couple of cases:

```
{
    "title": "Movie title",
    "images": [
        "http://www.url.com/img_0.jpg",
        "http://www.url.com/img_1.jpg",
        "http://www.url.com/img_2.jpg",
        "http://www.url.com/img_3.jpg",
        "http://www.url.com/img_4.jpg"
    ],
    "actors": [
        "Steven Berkoff",
        "Nikolaj Coster-Waldau",
        "Julie Cox"
    ],
    "directors": "Simon Aeby"
},
{
    "title": "Another movie",
    "images": "http://www.url.com/img_1.jpg",
    "actors": "actor 1"
    "directors": [
        "Justin Bieber",
        "Justin Timberlake"
    ]
}
```

The question is, using JSON.net, how can I create a converter that deals with this problem? I've been scouring the internet, but still haven't found a solution.

Another spin on the same question: If a field is either a List of strings or a simple string, how do I make JSON.NET create a List either way (and if just a simple string, create a list with one member)

EDIT: This REST-service is out of my control

Comment: is this your service or third party? i would suggest to edit service if possible. because you cant serialize fileld to array if it's not an array in json.

Comment: or you can do deserialize to an object and then map them to your classes

Comment: Updated the general post to make things more clear

Comment: A lot of APIs using scripting languages like JS returns something like that. Most common case is error message returned as (single string) or error message returned as (list of strings). As it is not always shows in docs, need to do many queries to API to get this issue. Custom JSON converter should check what type is the property in Json and convert it. In this case to List of Strings.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

<strike>Ok, I did it for fun, but don't think is useful or the best way, anyway...</strike>

Declaring the "dynamic" attributes as object and then create methods to obtain the properties as something like ImagesAsList or ImagesAsString. I did it with Extension Methods.....

```
var movies = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Movie>>(str);
```

Class

```
class Movie
{

    [JsonProperty("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("images")]
    public object Images { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("actors")]
    public object Actor { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("directors")]
    public object Directors { get; set; }
}
```

Extension Methods

```
static class MovieExtension
{
    public static List<string> ImagesAsList(this Movie m)
    {
        var jArray = (m.Images as JArray);
        if (jArray == null) return null;

        return jArray.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList();
    }

    public static string ImagesAsString(this Movie m)
    {
        return m.Images as string;
    }

}
```

**EDIT**

After reading @yamen comments I did some changes like:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.Converters.Add(new MoviesConverter());

var movies = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Movie>>(str, settings);
```

Class

```
class Movie
{

    [JsonProperty("title")]
    public List<string> Title { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("images")]
    public List<string> Images { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("actors")]
    public List<string> Actor { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("directors")]
    public List<string> Directors { get; set; }
}
```

Converter

```
class MoviesConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(string)) || (objectType == typeof(List<string>)) ;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartArray)
        {
            var l = new List<string>();
            reader.Read();
            while (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.EndArray)
            {
                l.Add(reader.Value as string);

                reader.Read();
            }
            return l;
        }
        else
        {
            return new List<string> { reader.Value as string };
        }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        //ToDo here we can decide to write the json as 
        //if only has one attribute output as string if it has more output as list
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think there's any need to declare as object. Declare always as List<string> (or List<T>) and simply return a single element when the underlying JSON is not an array. This is how the API should behave anyway, so coding your system in this way is future proofing as well. Added bonus is having an explicit mapping layer.

Comment: Ok, did some changes and extended the JsonCovert Class

Comment: This answer should be very favorable to the current selected answer by yamen. It makes good use of JSON.NET's converters and any generic parsing will still work as long as you decorate your objects properly :) +1

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, this helped greatly with handling the ridiculous "json" that sendgrid provides with their batched event api ("Category" can either be a single string property OR an array of string...wonder who dreamed that gem up!).

Comment: Since I'm lazy, I was looking for that answer exactly. Thanks, But I would add a comment for others that might be interesting: instead of using the settings for adding the converter, you can use the attribute: [JsonConverter(typeof(MoviesConverter))] on your specific properties. The serializer will use it when it serialize.

Answer (score 4):

You won't be able to serialise directly to an object, but you can do so manually without too much effort. JSON.Net contains LINQ to JSON. First define a method that will always return a list of type T even if the underlying JSON is not an array:

```
public List<T> getSingleOrArray<T>(JToken token)
{
    if (token.HasValues)
    {
        return token.Select(m => m.ToObject<T>()).ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        return new List<T> { token.ToObject<T>() };
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
JObject m1 = JObject.Parse(@"{
""title"": ""Movie title"",
""images"": [
    ""http://www.url.com/img_0.jpg"",
    ""http://www.url.com/img_1.jpg""
],
""actors"": [
    ""Steven Berkoff"",
    ""Julie Cox""
],
""directors"": ""Simon Aeby""
}");

JObject m2 = JObject.Parse(@"{
""title"": ""Another movie"",
""images"": ""http://www.url.com/img_1.jpg"",
""actors"": ""actor 1"",
""directors"": [
    ""Justin Bieber"",
    ""Justin Timberlake""
]
}");

IList<String> m1_directors = getSingleOrArray<string>(m1["directors"]);
IList<String> m2_directors = getSingleOrArray<string>(m2["directors"]);
```

m1_directory is a list with a single element, m2_directors is a list with two elements.