# MVC Binding for AJAX Request With IEnumerable<string>

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, model-binding

Here's the situation I'm facing right now. I have an action in my MVC controller that looks as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult MyAction(int id, IEnumerable<string> strings, bool trueFalse, string anotherString, bool anotherTrueFalse) {}
```

I access this through a `jQuery $.ajax` call as follows:

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'json',
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
data: {"id":12345,"strings":["onestring"],"trueFalse":false,"anotherString":"Woo String","anotherTrueFalse":false},
//Success/Error handlers here
});
```

Now, the issue I'm seeing is this: Regardless of the data being sent, `id`, `trueFalse`, `anotherString` and `anotherTrueFalse` are all being bound *correctly* when I debug my controller action and inspect the parameters being bound to my action.

The issue is with `strings`: if I send a JSON array with a single string (as above), **it never gets bound** to the `IEnumerable<string>` in my action. If I send something like this instead:

`"strings":["onestring", "twostring"]`

Then it gets bound properly as an `IEnumerable` with two entries.

What's going on here, what am I missing?

Note: I've just been trying to get the mapping to work first so it's still a bit messy. I'll be cleaning this up by putting all five of these properties into a view model so I have just one object being bound here - this may resolve the issue altogether. But still, it's curious to me that this doesn't work when the JSON array only has one entry.

**Addendum 1**: In my AJAX above, that's essentially what's being sent in the request to the server, but I'm actually building that object and then passing it to JSON.stringify -- just attempting to make the problem statement as simple as possible. What you see is what the browser sends to the controller action.

**Addendum 2**: Placing all of these properties into their own view model has cleaned things up a bit, but the binding issues still remain. Also, switching from `IEnumerable<string>` to `string[]` also exhibits the same issues, so there is something I am fundamentally missing about how MVC performs model binding for us.

Comment: Was my answer able to help you?

Comment: It did, thank you. I'll give you an upvote, and mark yours as the answer now unless there's some other less involved solution to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is when you receive a json array with one element, it will get cast as just plain `string`. Multiple elements get cast correctly to the `IEnumerable`. In JSON, a single element is treated as a dictionary and not an array. I would suggest using JSON.NET to handle the parsing for you as the default model binder will cause trouble with this one.

More information can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10122308/118224