# Serializing POJO to json with some value as String or list

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

Assume I have this POJO:

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class Model {

    @JsonProperty(value="data")
    private String dataStr;
    private List<String> data;
}
```

And it should be serialized to

```
{ "data": "hello" }
```

or

```
{
    "data": [
        "hello",
        "world"
    ]
}
```

depending on some conditions. How can I do this with Jackson ?

The class given above doesn't work. The only one solution I've found so far is

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class Model {

    @JsonProperty
    private Object data;
}
```

but it's not the best one. I think there is a way to do something like `@OneOf`. Any ideas?

Comment: The first example has two fields named "data" and they have different types, too.

Comment: But it doesn't work. I'm using Spring and any attempts to return this object returns 406 http status code.

Comment: That is the point @Stefoan is making. You're going to struggle if you define multiple fields with the same name. I don't think jackson can just work it out for you. If possible, I'd suggest removing the `@JsonProperty` or renaming the list element to `dataList` to stop the confusion.

Comment: Sure, it can be done. But it's the same situation as in many REST services. You can see one of examples here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10121804/2139038

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you found out, you can indeed use type `java.lang.Object`. Another similar approach would be to use `JsonNode`, if you can pre-build response type.

Another way to go is to use annotations `@JsonValue` and a container type; you could then isolate details in separate holder class like:

```
public class Model {
    public Wrapper data;
}

public class Wrapper {
    @JsonValue
    public Object methodToBuildValue() {
       // code to figure out what to return, String, List etc
    }
}
```

and in this case whatever `methodToBuildValue()` returns is serialized instead of `Wrapper` value itself.
This gives more flexibility and bit more typing; you could have different accessors for `Wrapper` for your own code to use.

Not sure what the best way is, but I would actually just suggest that use of such loosely typed JSON structures is probably not a good idea -- it is not easily mappable to statically typed languages like Java or C#, and I am not sure what the benefit is. I am assuming however that you did not define JSON structure to use so maybe that's a moot point.