# In c# json object has only 1 data and json.Count is not working

Tags: c#, json

While extracting Json, I get as result either :

```
{"uri":"./factory/languages/de-de","name":"de-de"}
```

or

```
[{
        "uri": "./factory/languages/de-de",
        "name": "de-de"
    }, {
        "uri": "./factory/languages/en-us",
        "name": "en-us"
    }, {
        "uri": "./factory/languages/he-il",
        "name": "he-il"
    }
]
```

The json object returns one item or a List. When the object consists of only single data then `json.Count` property is not working.

```
{
   // Parse the response body.
   //Make sure to add a reference to System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll
   var dataObjects = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;  
   Console.WriteLine("Status : {0}\nReason : ({1})", (int)response.StatusCode, response.StatusCode);
   Console.WriteLine("Data from server :\n"+dataObjects);
   dynamic json = JValue.Parse(dataObjects);
   Console.WriteLine("\nData extracted by parsing in JSON format");
   //Console.WriteLine(json.Count);
   for(int i = 0; i<json.Count;i++) // error here
   {
      Console.WriteLine("\n"+(i+1)+".");
      Console.WriteLine("name :"+json[i].name);
      Console.WriteLine("uri :"+json[i].uri);
   }
}
```

It is not entering the for loop. But if I print directly json.name it's working.

I want to write code that works for both single data and multiple data.

Comment: What is your `dataObjects` type? It can be one `Item` or a List<Item>`? If it's a list with only one item a simple foreach will be the simpliest solution https://www.dotnetperls.com/foreach

Comment: What is the type return? Is it an object or a list of object? or both because it depends?

Comment: Can you give an example of making the dataObjects as a list of item? so that i can always make it as a list and use foreach or even Count property works there.

Comment: May I ask for little exemple of dataObjects when there is multiple and when there is only one object? Because one service will have a return type and won't switch the return type from object to list object.

Comment: one object :  {"uri":"./factory/languages/de-de","name":"de-de"} .                        multiple object :[{"uri":"./factory/languages/de-de","name":"de-de"},{"uri":"./factory/languages/en-us","name":"en-us"},{"uri":"./factory/languages/he-il","name":"he-il"}]

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121804/json-net-field-is-either-string-or-liststring

Comment: I dont want to create another class . I want some different approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Temporary Solution :

I got some solution. I checked the return string for '[' at its first index, if it doesn't contain then i will add '[' and ']' at the start and end of the string respectively . 
Code snippet :

```
 string dataObjects = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;  
 //Make sure to add a reference to System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll
 Console.WriteLine("Status : {0}\nReason : ({1})",
                        (int)response.StatusCode, response.StatusCode);
Console.WriteLine("Data from server :\n"+dataObjects);
dynamic json;
if(dataObjects[0]!='[')
{
    json = JValue.Parse("["+dataObjects+"]"); 
}
else
{
    json = JValue.Parse(dataObjects);
}

Console.WriteLine("\nData extracted by parsing in JSON format");
Console.WriteLine(json.Count);
for(int i = 0; i<json.Count;i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\n"+(i+1)+".");
    Console.WriteLine("name :"+json[i].name);
    Console.WriteLine("uri :"+json[i].uri);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add reference of

> System.Net.Http.Formatting

as exception said in order to digest or read json properly, and it can be installed by using nuget package manager and type

> Install-Package System.Net.Http.Formatting.Extension -Version 5.2.3

and also you are running your for loop <0 means if it starts with 0 then it will not run because  stopping condition is < 0

so replace with "="

```
for(int i = 0; i<=json.Count;i++)
   {
   }
```

Comment: I have included it and extracting from jvalue which is there in Newtonsoft.Json.Linq property . That's what i said it is working when json value consists multiple values but not in single value.

Comment: @AkshayKanagali now please check the solution

Comment: its not working. Actually when i try to print the json.Count it is giving me error: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.Console.WriteLine(string) and 'System.Console.WriteLine(char[])